# VB.Net - RadioButton - Text on multiple lines

Tags: vb.net, radio-button, multiline

I'm writing a quiz application.

Every question has 5 possible answers, so I've used 5 RadioButtons to get the answer selected.

It happens that the text of some answers is too long and part of it isn't shown.

Is it possible to show the text of a RadioButton on multiple lines?

Comment: `radioButton1.AutoSize = False;`

Comment: @LarsTech I've altready set Autosize = false but the text still stay on one line

Comment: Shrink the width.  Did you change any of the default properties? because the text should automatically wrap.

Comment: with autosize off, make it long enough and tall enough to fit the longest answer in the IDE

Comment: It was my fault: the RadioButton wasn't TALL enough. Thanks to everyone ;)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code on the Radiobutton's TextChanged Event. And change the Radiobutton's Property (AutoSize=False).

```
Private Sub RadioButtonOptionD_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButtonOptionD.TextChanged
    Dim s As New Size()
    s.Width = RadioButtonOptionD.Size.Width
    s.Height = 0
    If RadioButtonOptionD.Text.Length() <= 100 Then
        s.Height = 60
        RadioButtonOptionD.Size = s
    ElseIf RadioButtonOptionD.Text.Length() <= 200
        s.Height = 80
        RadioButtonOptionD.Size = s
    ElseIf RadioButtonOptionD.Text.Length() > 200
        s.Height = 100
        RadioButtonOptionD.Size = s
    End If
```

Adjusting the height of the RadioButton according to the lines of its text.
if the RadioButton has more then 2 lines? then it will change the height of the Radio button up to 150.

```
    If RadioButtonOptionD.Text.Split(vbNewLine).Count >= 2 Then  
        s.Height = 150
        RadioButtonOptionD.Size = s
    End If
    RadioButtonOptionD.Refresh()
End Sub
```